Select and color linestring geometry through plotly
In the below Shiny app, I'd like for 3 improvements (with 1 as the main priority):

For the user to be able to select lines easily with the lasso tool. Currently, lines are only captured if points are captured. In other words, in the GIF below, I'd like both selections to work (turn the lines blue).

For the coloration to happen efficiently after ggplot(), as well as ggplotly(). We can achieve this after ggplot() using ggplot2::annotate(), but for annotating after ggplotly(), add_segments() will not work with a key aesthetic (needed in my case). We get the error unique() applies only to vectors.

For zoom not to reset after selection.


The .dxf file is in this repo.

Shiny App:
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)
library(bslib)

dxf <- st_read(here('d3map/giraffe360_demo_residential.dxf'))

dxf_gp <- dxf |> 
  group_by(geometry_type = st_geometry_type(dxf)) |>
  nest()

dxf_lns <- dxf_gp |> 
  filter(geometry_type == "LINESTRING") |> 
  unnest(cols = c(data)) |> 
  mutate(
    geometry = st_zm(geometry, "LINESTRING"),
    ini = st_startpoint(geometry),
    end = st_endpoint(geometry)
  )

dxf_lns <- dxf_lns |> 
  mutate(
    across(
      c(ini, end),
      list(
        x = \(point) st_coordinates(point)[,1],
        y = \(point) st_coordinates(point)[,2]
      ),
      .names = "{.fn}{.col}"
    )
  )

dxf_lns$key <- row.names(dxf_lns)
dxf_lns$col <- "black"

ui <- bslib::page_fluid(
  plotlyOutput("floor_plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
  dxf_lns <- reactiveVal(dxf_lns)
  
  output$floor_plot <- renderPlotly({
    dat <- dxf_lns()
    d <- event_data("plotly_selected")
    
    if (!is.null(d)) {
      dat[dat$key %in% d$key, "col"] <- "blue"
    }
    
    p <- ggplot(dat, aes(geometry = geometry, col = I(col), key = key)) +
      geom_sf(data = dat) +
      geom_point(aes(x = xini, y = yini), alpha = 0) +
      theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())
    
    p |>
      ggplotly() |>
      config(scrollZoom = TRUE) |> 
      event_register("plotly_selected") |>
      layout(dragmode = "lasso")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Annotate attempt:
p <- ggplot(dxf_lns, aes(geometry = geometry, key = key,)) +
       geom_sf(data = dxf_lns) +
       geom_point(aes(x = xini, y = yini), alpha = 0) +
       theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())

pp <- p |> 
  ggplotly() |>
  event_register("plotly_selected") |>
  config(scrollZoom = TRUE) |> 
  layout(dragmode = "lasso", showlegend = FALSE) 

pp |> 
  add_segments(x = 1, xend = 100, y = 1, yend = 100)


I've only seen lasso used to select points

@HubertL I'm thinking then I can use the brush extents' intersection with lines.
I added 2 unrelated requests to my question.

One possibility would be to use the brushed event instead. You get a list of points which you could transform into a geometry (a convex hull for example) and then check which geometry has an intersection with it and color it accordingly:
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dxf_lns <- reactiveVal(st_as_sf(dxf_lns)) ## make sure dxf_lns stays an sf object
  
  output$floor_plot <- renderPlotly({
    dat <- dxf_lns()
    d <- event_data("plotly_brushed")
    if (!is.null(d)) {
      cvh <- d |>
        do.call(cbind, args = _) |>
        st_multipoint() |>
        st_convex_hull()
      idx <- c(
        st_intersects(cvh, dat, sparse = FALSE)
      ) |>
        which()
      if (length(idx)) {
        dat[idx, "col"] <- "blue"
      }
    }
    p <- ggplot(dat, aes(geometry = geometry, key = key)) +
      geom_sf(data = dat, aes(col = I(col))) +
      geom_point(aes(x = xini, y = yini), alpha = 0) +
      theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())
    p |>
      ggplotly() |>
      event_register("plotly_brushed") |>
      layout(dragmode = "lasso")
  })
}



Using a convex hull is perfect. I believe request 2 is not possible with plotly. And request 3 is a separate question that may not be solvable with code.

Perhaps 2 can be done using plotlyProxy() and adding traces.
